# java.io.InvalidClassException: com.kingmo.utils.abstractions.SerializableLocation; no valid constructor but I have the proper constructor

Tags: java, serialization, bukkit

I'm beyond confused. I had it working, went and did other stuff and came back to it's not working.

Right now my code is

```
package com.kingmo.utils.abstractions;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;

public class SerializableLocation extends Location implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SerializableLocation(Location loc) {
        super(loc.getWorld(), loc.getX(), loc.getY(), loc.getZ());
    }

    public SerializableLocation(Map<String, Object> ser) {
        this(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld((String) ser.get("world")), (int) ser.get("x"), (int) ser.get("y"),
                (int) ser.get("z")));
    
        
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> serialize() {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("world", this.getWorld().getName());
        map.put("x", this.getBlockX());
        map.put("y", this.getBlockY());
        map.put("z", this.getBlockZ());
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * (int) (this.getX() + this.getY() + this.getZ() + this.getWorld().getName().hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof SerializableLocation))
            return false;

        Location loc = (Location) o;
        
        return loc.getX() == this.getX() && loc.getY() == this.getY() && loc.getZ() == this.getZ()
                && loc.getWorld().getName().equals(this.getWorld().getName());
    }

}
```

As you can see I have the SerializableLocation#init(Map<String, Object> ser) which is required for Serializable classes. But it still says I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `SerializableLocation` implements `Serializable` but its parent class `Location` doesn't. For serialization to work in this case, the parent class needs to have a no-arg constructor, but it doesn't. Given you talk about a required constructor taking `Map<String, Object>`, it's likely you're getting `Serializable` and [`ConfigurationSerializable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/serialization/ConfigurationSerializable.html) mixed up, since the latter needs that but the former doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt mean configurationSerializable and may infact be using Serializable wrong but oops idrc. I think Ill be able to figure my stuff out. Ill respond later if I can